# How do I take proper voltage measurements on device with multiple voltage sources sharing the same ground?

Tags: multimeter, voltage-measurement, crt

If you recognize me, it's in reference to CRT scopes again. I don't understand how to take proper voltage readings on the circuits. An example is the heating element in the CRT. When I hook both test leads to both pins of the election gun, I get the proper 6.4V reading. However, when my negative lead is hooked to chassis (HV probe) each pin going to the electron gun measures at over 1KV.

I'm confused as to how 30V can share the same ground as 1500V in the first place, but what do I need to know to choose which negative side to probe with? The manual for my HV probe tells me to hook the ground lead to the chassis, but in the case of the election gun, that makes it look like the electron gun is receiving over 1KV, which I know is incorrect because it's glowing nicely instead of bursting into flames. I guess the other possibility is to test components directly instead of only testing it's positive and using the chassis. Do I sometimes ground to chassis, and sometimes ground on the individual component?

Thanks again for all the help

Comment: Jared, you have raised numerous questions and got plenty of answers so, before you go much further you should consider formally accepting the most appropriate answer to your questions. If there is no resolving answer then raise a comment for clarification if answers are present.

Comment: Hey Andy, nobody has answered me about this yet, and I haven't asked yet. Is there an issue with me posting too many questions?

Comment: No, but most people twig that they need to (at some point) start "paying the piper" and that payment is answer acceptance and/or upvotes on your previous 12 questions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about this. I haven't been here for long, I didn't even realize I could do those things. I'll go back and do that. Thanks

Comment: @Jared: See [Help - Someone answers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to understand how this works.

Comment: I just figured it out. I hope everybody here understands how much I appreciate all of them. This forum is really the only way I can get help for this big jump in knowledge I'm trying to aquire. I read a lot and test a lot, but it's a really difficult thing to try to tackle on your own.

Comment: But the answer to one of your questions does explain it.  Ground is just a reference.  Some places in a circuit will have a solid voltage relative to ground, others won't.

Comment: That doesn't tell me how I should be measuring voltages. A good example is the one I provided in this question, of two different grounds giving me 2 different measurements. I need to know how to take measurements on a complex system like this, not just electrical theory. The whole question I just posted was about testing method, not wanting to know theory.

Answer (score 2):

*Let me first say that, while high-voltage electronics may seem interesting and fascinating, it is also very dangerous. A CRT supply can deliver 20kV at up to 20mA, which is twice as much needed to kill a person in a painful, long, and bad way. I strongly suggest that anyone interested in electronics forego experimenting with, measuring, or attempting repair or modification of any kind of high-voltage equipment.*  There is still *tons* to learn without putting yourself in danger because of a fascination.

> I need to know how to take measurements on a complex system like this, not just electrical theory. The whole question I just posted was about testing method, not wanting to know theory.

Jared, you've got this backwards. You *need* theory to understand how to *test*.

Now "ground" is just a reference point.

Consider the following circuit. Long story short, a transformer is physically coils of wire sharing magnetic flux. The coils themselves are isolated, unless we connect them together. A transformer works on the principle of changing magnetic flux inducing a voltage in wire. Since they only work on *changing* magnetic flux, AC must be used, not DC. Put voltage and current change in one coil, and this will appear on all other coils, according to the turns ratio. If the primary (input, driven side) has 10 turns, and the secondary 10 turns, then 1v in will produce just slightly less than 1v out due to losses. If the secondary had instead 10,000 turns, then slightly less than 10kV would be output. Notice where the grounds are placed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foLgt0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you take more than two coils (depicted as four due to limitations of the schematic editor) you should be able to see how it is possible for "ground" to be misleading - the 6.3v output *only* measures as 6.3v if referenced from the 10kV output.

Note that if using an oscilloscope to measure CRT's:

- The probe's ground clip or pin is physically connected to the knurled grip of the connector and chassis of the 'scope. *Many* people have been shocked (or worse) forgetting this.
- The ground clip is *also* connected to the ground pin of the scope's power plug. If plugged into a grounded outlet, then touching the ground clip to certain points in a circuit will short them to Earth ground, likely causing damage to the circuit, the probe, 'scope, or all the above.
- To get around this, often a scope will be powered from an isolation transformer and the Earth ground disconnected. This allows the technician to ground the scope to *anything, without fear of damage. However, now they must remember that the scope body can be "live" and potentially lethal. Note that, an isolation transformer is usually rated for a maximum isolation of about *5kV. Some may be less than this. So if measuring a 20kV node, this can grossly exceed the isolation rating of the transformer and scope. Hence, not a good idea to measure CRT's, even *with* an isolation transformer.

The only way to measure a 10kV node is with a high-voltage probe. These have special high-voltage-rated resistors inside to safely drop that voltage down to a sane level and disallow arcing-over inside. Still, the "ground" of the scope cannot be placed at that level. So in the case of the above schematic, subtract the node differences (10,006.3 - 10,000) = 6.3v. Most scopes have a math function built-in; just probe both nodes at the same time (both with HV probes), do a subtraction on them from the scope, and read out the difference.

Answer (score 1):

> The manual for my HV probe tells me to hook the ground lead to the
>   chassis, but in the case of the election gun, that makes it look like
>   the electron gun is receiving over 1KV, which I know is incorrect because
>   it's glowing nicely instead of bursting into flames.

The electron gun *is* receiving over 1 kV. The heater is receiving 6.4V relative to the electron gun (it is done this way rather than powering the heater with ground-referenced 6.3V to prevent arcing between the heater and electron gun Cathode).

A voltage reading is always between two points, neither of which has to be ground. When you read the heater voltage with your meter, both leads of the meter were at close to -1 kV relative to chassis ground. The manual for your HV probe tells you to hook the ground lead to the chassis for two reasons - firstly because the CRT's high voltage supply is referenced to ground, and secondly for safety (eg. you *could* connect it the other way way around, but then the probe's 'ground' lead would have ~-1 kV on it, which could be a shock hazard).

> what do I need to know to choose which negative side to probe with?

You need to know what two points the voltage you are interested in is between. In the case of the CRT heater you want to measure across the heater terminals, even though they both are at ~-1 kV. You don't need a high voltage probe for this, but you *do* need an insulated meter that can handle 1 kV between it and ground (or the person holding it). If your multimeter is [CAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_category) rated for a working voltage of 1000 V then it should be safe, if not then you risk being shocked through the case or leads.

But how to know what voltages to expect? For that you need intimate knowledge of the equipment you are working on, which means:-

1. familiarity with the type of device and components used in it, circuit design and operation.
2. Schematics and component layout.

So you should learn about how CRT scopes work and the circuits used in them, study the schematics of several models, and if possible get the service manual for the scope you are working on.

Poking around in equipment whose circuit you don't understand is a waste of time, and could be dangerous for you and the equipment. If you can't get the schematics for the exact model or a very similar one then trace relevant parts of it *before* making any measurements. There is no point measuring voltages if you don't know what they should be!